# Avoid select from dual Union in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i have this data:

```
 'DJORDAN','ADAVIS','MJONES','DPRESTOM','PSMITH'
```

I need convert the data to a cursor o in others cases using to a INSERT
Then i do:

```
  Select 'DJORDAN' User_Code from dual 
  union
  Select 'ADAVIS' User_Code from dual 
  union
  Select 'MJONES' User_Code  from dual 
  union
  Select 'DPRESTOM' User_Code  from dual 
  union
  Select 'PSMITH' User_Code from dual ;
```

Are there any alternative to Union DUal for this purpose?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: even with this approach you can use `union all` in lieu of `union` since you know all the values are distinct.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a collection, for example:

```
select * from SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL ('DJORDAN','ADAVIS','MJONES','DPRESTOM','PSMITH');
```

Or for older versions of Oracle:

```
select * from TABLE(SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL ('DJORDAN','ADAVIS','MJONES','DPRESTOM','PSMITH'));
```

Comment: Does it run ? for me i have to do like "select * FROM TABLE(SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL('g','h'));" in oracle 19c

Comment: Ah, I'm on 20C, so it's slicker!

Comment: `select * from sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll ('A','B','C');` works for me in 19.0.0.

Comment: @ William Robertson :- For me I was running it in PL/SQL Developer tool (13.0.6) SQL window and was facing issues (running the query results in ORA-03114: not connected to ORACLE
, After I saw your comment I tried with SQL * command prompt it works fine and I am not sure why the issue with the IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another simple solution:

```sql
create table t1 (user_code varchar2 (10))
/
begin
    insert into t1 (user_code) 
    select trim (column_value) user_code 
    from xmlTable (
        replace (q'"'DJORDAN','ADAVIS','MJONES','DPRESTOM','PSMITH'"', '''', '"'));
end;
/
select * from t1;
```

Result:

```
USER_CODE
----------
DJORDAN
ADAVIS
MJONES
DPRESTOM
PSMITH
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, with quite a lot more typing, assuming that list of names is - actually - a *string*, you could split it to rows and then insert into the table. Something like this:

```
SQL> create table test (col varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test
  2  with temp (col) as
  3    (select q'['DJORDAN','ADAVIS','MJONES','DPRESTOM','PSMITH']' from dual)
  4  select regexp_substr(replace(col, chr(39), null), '[^,]+', 1, level) val
  5  from temp
  6  connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ',') + 1;

5 rows created.

SQL> select * from test;

COL
--------------------
DJORDAN
ADAVIS
MJONES
DPRESTOM
PSMITH

SQL>
```

---

Or, if you use Apex, its `APEX_STRING.SPLIT` also does the job:

```
select column_value
from apex_string.split('DJORDAN,ADAVIS,MJONES,DPRESTOM,PSMITH', ',');
```

[image]